# How to Auto Generate JavaScript code using GO

Tags: javascript, go

I need to auto generate a JS code in GO depending on input set of rules. For example, let's say I have an app in GO that receives a Json containing a set of rules:

```
{
  "enabled": true,
  "rulesLimit": 3,
  "Rules": [
    {
      "name": "Not Dave or Ted",
      "enabled": true,
      "id": 1,
      "trigger": {
        "operator": "AND",
        "conditions": [
          {
            "operator": "NOT EQUAL",
            "value": "Dave"
          },
          {
            "operator": "NOT EQUAL",
            "value": "Ted"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Only from home",
      "enabled": true,
      "id": 2,
      "trigger": {
        "conditions": [
          {
            "operator": "EQUAL",
            "urlValue": "Home"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
]
}
```

The app needs to auto generate a JS code with a function containing the requested rules:

```
function applyRules(){     
    if  (person[name] === "Dave" || person[name] === "Ted") {         
        return     
    }          
    if  (person[address] !== "Home") {         
        return     
    } 
} 
applyRules();
```

I currently researching what is the best way to approach it. I thought at first about using the template with placeholders using [Go Template](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#pkg-overview), but when I started implementing it the complexity was a bit much. Is there some other approach, tool or method I could look into that might do what I need?
Thank you

Comment: When templates become difficult, you can switch to generating code with the AST. That is, find a Go implementation of the JavaScript AST, then write code that builds the target code using the AST, then write the result into a file. If you can't find one, you'll have to write one yourself, it does not have to be complete, just those parts that you need to generate.

Comment: If you're interested in the topic of code generation in Go, you may find this [Go Time episode](https://changelog.com/gotime/170) helpful.